# jersey: possible to inherit path from parent class

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In the spirit of DRY I'm trying to bundle annotations and shared code that apply to all my REST resources in a central class. Sharing parts of the path does not seem to work.

Let's say I have two REST resources at `/v1/users` and `/v1/items`. The Jersey resources both extend the same parent class `V1BaseResource`. Can they inherit the `v1`-part of the path?

Example:

```
@Path("v1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   // applies to all child-classes
public class V1BaseResource {

    // maybe even some shared code
}
```

UsersResource

```
@Path("users")
public class UsersResource extends V1BaseResource {

    @GET
    public Response getUsers() ...
}
```

ItemsResource

```
@Path("items")
public class ItemsResource extends V1BaseResource {

    @GET
    public Response getItems() ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the `@Path` annotation of the actual resources *overwrites the path*, not *adds to it*.

Is this possible (with out the use of [sub-resource locators](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2549))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the JSR, it's not possible :

> If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on the superclass or interface method are ignored.

Here is the JSR : [JSR-339](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf).
See *Section 3.6*.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! would you be so kind and add a link to the quote? Much appreciated.